# TYPO3 upgrade 9.5-10.4 'SchedulerCommand' not found

Tags: typo3

I upgraded from 9.5.30 to 10.4. via composer. Everything looks fine but I cannot run the upgrade wizard:

```
 ./vendor/bin/typo3 upgrade:list -a

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Command\SchedulerCommand' not found
thrown in file /var/www/typo3/htl-villach/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
in line 3475
```

My environment is a composer based installation on Ubuntu 18.04 / MySQL 8.
The upgrade of the same installation worked on a ddev based dev environment.

Backend and frontend look good, but the TYPO3 CLI seems to be broken.

Any hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: `typo3/cms-scheduler` has been required? And it exists? Does composer find the packed and generates the autoloading files accordingly?

Comment: Thanks a lot, requiring `typo3/cms-scheduler` did it. Funny thing is, I did not need to require it in my ddev environment.

Comment: Maybe it's a requirement of another package in the dev system? Or one of a package in `require-dev` section? Try `composer why typo3/cms-scheduler`  in your ddev environment to find out more details.

Comment: It looks like both ddev and prod environments tell me `ddev composer why typo3/cms-scheduler
typo3/cms-base-distribution  dev-master  requires  typo3/cms-scheduler (^10) ` after manually require-ing it. Only prod complained at runtime. Anyway, I required `typo3/cms-scheduler` to both environments and I live with some uncertainity :-)